# what is this new "in" keyword in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I have just opened a swift 2 project with last Xcode version.
Xcode suggest me to auto convert my code to swift 3.

Here is something strange:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}


func tableView(_ tableView: MyTableView,  numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 10
}
```

If you look, Xcode added a "in" keyword for the numberOfSections method. But he did nothing for the numberOfRowsInSection method.
I do not understand why.

What is this "in" keyword in Swift 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a keyword. It's the name of the first parameter in the method.

In Swift2 the method was...

```
func numberOfSections(inTableView: UITableView) -> Int
```

... and it would be called like...

```
numberOfSections(tableView)
```

In Swift 3 there is a lot of emphasis on making function names more verb based and removing redundant inferred or implied type from the method names. Also, the first parameter name of methods is now required.

All these changes lead to the name being updated to what you have seen and the call becomes...

```
numberOfSections(in: tableView)
```

You can read more about the changes in Swift 3 in [Apple's API Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/).

Comment: there is no : (double dot)

Comment: @Bob5421 what do you mean there is no double dot? That's how you call the method if you want to run it. That's how you call any Swift method.